# Error parsing json excel vba

Tags: json, vba, excel

I am using the jsonConverter.bas file from here https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON.

When parsing json file most of the files are successfully parsed but there is issue with one file which returns `Error Parsing JSON`.

Here is the json file if anyone is interested: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=45560953732509718973

Error parsing JSON:
ï»¿{  "star
^
Expecting '{' or '['

Along with the JsonConverter.bas file I am using below sub:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myPath As String, myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim fD As Long, fColD As Long
Dim cet

Sub getDataFromJSON()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

  myExtension = "*.json"

  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  Do While myFile <> ""
        Call getData
        myFile = Dir
  Loop

Data.Activate
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
    Application.EnableEvents = True:    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub getData()
' Advanced example: Read .json file and load into sheet (Windows-only)
' (add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime)
' {"values":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c": 3},...]}

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream, JsonText As String, Parsed As Dictionary

Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile(myPath & myFile, ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close

Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)

' Prepare and write values to sheet
Dim Value As Dictionary

With Data
    fD = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    fColD = 34

    For Each Value In Parsed("events")
        .Cells(fD, fColD) = Value("t")
        .Cells(fD, fColD + 1) = Value("e")
        .Cells(fD, fColD + 2) = Value("ty")
        .Cells(fD, fColD + 3) = Value("x")
        .Cells(fD, fColD + 4) = Value("y")
        fColD = fColD + 5
    Next Value

      .Range("A" & fD) = Parsed("startTime")
      .Range("B" & fD) = Parsed("websitePageUrl")
      .Range("C" & fD) = Parsed("session")("visitorId")
      .Range("D" & fD) = Parsed("session")("playbackUrl")
      .Range("E" & fD) = Parsed("visitTime")
      .Range("F" & fD) = Parsed("engagementTime")
      .Range("G" & fD) = Parsed("pageTitle")
      .Range("H" & fD) = Parsed("url")
      .Range("I" & fD) = Parsed("viewportWidth")
      .Range("J" & fD) = Parsed("viewportHeight")
      .Range("K" & fD) = Parsed("session")("id")
      .Range("L" & fD) = Parsed("session")("created")
      .Range("M" & fD) = Parsed("session")("lastActivity")
      .Range("N" & fD) = Parsed("session")("duration")
      .Range("O" & fD) = Parsed("session")("pages")
      .Range("P" & fD) = Parsed("session")("country")
      .Range("Q" & fD) = Parsed("session")("city")
      .Range("R" & fD) = Parsed("session")("isp")
      .Range("S" & fD) = Parsed("session")("lang")
      .Range("T" & fD) = Parsed("session")("userAgent")
      .Range("U" & fD) = Parsed("session")("browser")
      .Range("V" & fD) = Parsed("session")("browserVersion")
      .Range("W" & fD) = Parsed("session")("os")
      .Range("X" & fD) = Parsed("session")("osVersion")
      .Range("Y" & fD) = Parsed("session")("device")
      .Range("Z" & fD) = Parsed("session")("referrer")
      .Range("AA" & fD) = Parsed("session")("referrerType")
      .Range("AB" & fD) = Parsed("session")("screenRes")
      .Range("AC" & fD) = Parsed("session")("entryPage")

      'loadtimes
      cet = Split(Parsed("loadTimes"), ",")
      .Range("AD" & fD) = Trim(Split(cet(0), ":")(1))
      .Range("AE" & fD) = Trim(Split(cet(1), ":")(1))
      .Range("AF" & fD) = Trim(Split(cet(2), ":")(1))
      .Range("AG" & fD) = Trim(Split(cet(3), ":")(1))

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText) this line when it's trying to parse the json. The error is actually in the JsonConverter.bas file

Comment: Is it stopping on a specific line in JsonConverter.bas?  I would suggest also making a simplified version of the json file to try to determine where the error is in there.  Are the the (working) json files the same type of dataset?  (At first glance this json looks non-standard.)  If so, then the error must be in the data iteself, but determining which line of json is the problem, and which like of code is the problem, will help narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json file is encoded by UTF-8. So it did not work.
convert encoding utf-8 by this.

```
Function getString(path As String)
    Dim objStream As Object
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile path
        getString = .readtext
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Function
```

After converting, run your code.

```
Dim myPath As String, myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim fD As Long, fColD As Long
Dim cet

Sub getDataFromJSON()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

  myExtension = "*.json"

  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  Do While myFile <> ""
        Call getData
        myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Data.Activate
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
    Application.EnableEvents = True:    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub getData()
' Advanced example: Read .json file and load into sheet (Windows-only)
' (add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime)
' {"values":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c": 3},...]}

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream, JsonText As String, Parsed As Dictionary

'Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile(myPath & myFile, ForReading)
'JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
'JsonTS.Close
JsonText = getString(myPath & myFile) '<~~ convert utf-8 encode
Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)

' Prepare and write values to sheet
Dim Value As Dictionary

'With Data
With ActiveSheet
    fD = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    fColD = 34

    For Each Value In Parsed("events")
        .Cells(fD, fColD) = Value("t")
        .Cells(fD, fColD + 1) = Value("e")
        .Cells(fD, fColD + 2) = Value("ty")
        .Cells(fD, fColD + 3) = Value("x")
        .Cells(fD, fColD + 4) = Value("y")
        fColD = fColD + 5
    Next Value

      .Range("A" & fD) = Parsed("startTime")
      .Range("B" & fD) = Parsed("websitePageUrl")
      .Range("C" & fD) = Parsed("session")("visitorId")
      .Range("D" & fD) = Parsed("session")("playbackUrl")
      .Range("E" & fD) = Parsed("visitTime")
      .Range("F" & fD) = Parsed("engagementTime")
      .Range("G" & fD) = Parsed("pageTitle")
      .Range("H" & fD) = Parsed("url")
      .Range("I" & fD) = Parsed("viewportWidth")
      .Range("J" & fD) = Parsed("viewportHeight")
      .Range("K" & fD) = Parsed("session")("id")
      .Range("L" & fD) = Parsed("session")("created")
      .Range("M" & fD) = Parsed("session")("lastActivity")
      .Range("N" & fD) = Parsed("session")("duration")
      .Range("O" & fD) = Parsed("session")("pages")
      .Range("P" & fD) = Parsed("session")("country")
      .Range("Q" & fD) = Parsed("session")("city")
      .Range("R" & fD) = Parsed("session")("isp")
      .Range("S" & fD) = Parsed("session")("lang")
      .Range("T" & fD) = Parsed("session")("userAgent")
      .Range("U" & fD) = Parsed("session")("browser")
      .Range("V" & fD) = Parsed("session")("browserVersion")
      .Range("W" & fD) = Parsed("session")("os")
      .Range("X" & fD) = Parsed("session")("osVersion")
      .Range("Y" & fD) = Parsed("session")("device")
      .Range("Z" & fD) = Parsed("session")("referrer")
      .Range("AA" & fD) = Parsed("session")("referrerType")
      .Range("AB" & fD) = Parsed("session")("screenRes")
      .Range("AC" & fD) = Parsed("session")("entryPage")

      'loadtimes
      cet = Split(Parsed("loadTimes"), ",")
      .Range("AD" & fD) = Trim(Split(cet(0), ":")(1))
      .Range("AE" & fD) = Trim(Split(cet(1), ":")(1))
      .Range("AF" & fD) = Trim(Split(cet(2), ":")(1))
      .Range("AG" & fD) = Trim(Split(cet(3), ":")(1))

End With

End Sub
Function getString(path As String)
    Dim objStream As Object
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile path
        getString = .readtext
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Function
```